# Assign values from Numpy Array to Pandas DataFrame based on almost matching unix timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, unix-timestamp

I am given a 2D numpy array and a huge pandas DataFrame. A dummy example of them would look somewhat like this:

```
arr = np.array([[1648137283, 0],
                [1648137284, 1],
                [1648137285, 2],
                [1648137286, 3],
                .....
                [1658137287, 4],
                [1658137288, 5],
                [1658137289, 6]])

df.head(-6)
            unix         ...   value_a 
0           1643137283   ...     23
1           1643137284   ...     54
2           1643137285   ...     25
...          ...         ...     ...   
10036787    1653174068   ...     75
10036788    1653174069   ...     65
10036789    1653174070   ...     23
```

In the first column of `arr` is a unix timestamp and in the second an id-value. The DataFrame also has a column for the unix timestamp. My goal is to map the id-value from `arr` based on the unix timestamp to the corresponding timestamp of `df` in a separate new column called 'index'.

Now, these are probably important notes:

- `df` contains only a portion of all timestamps from `arr`
- `df` and `arr` have different lengths along the `axis=0`
- the timestamps in `df` are ordered in sequences and repeat themselves
- `arr` contains all unix timestamps from `df` but not the way around
- about 1% of the unix values do not match perfectly. My unix is in `unit='ms'`, some timestamps are off by +/-1 or +/-2, however, in my use cases they can bee seen as identical

I could do this within a loop or with `np.where()`. However, as `arr` and `df` are quite large, I was hoping for a fast solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to convert the numpy array to a mapping containing key-val pairs, where key is unix timestamps and value is correponding id, then you can use `series.map` to substitute/map the values in the given dataframe

```
df['index'] = df['unix'].map(dict(arr))
```

Sample output

```
                unix  ...  value_a  index
0         1643137283  ...       23      0
1         1643137284  ...       54      1
2         1643137285  ...       25      2
10036787  1653174068  ...       75      3
10036788  1653174069  ...       65      5
10036789  1653174070  ...       23      6
```

Comment: Cheers. This is a very elegant and fast solution. However, I now see that some unix timestamps are not completely identical. I am actually using unix with `unit='ms'`. So, even 1 ms off, which is in my use case pretty much identical, won´t fit anymore. Any way to have something similar here? Like in `pd.merge_as_of`?

Comment: @Zenia I guess in that case we can floor the unix timestamps to 10ms precision, then try map to substitute the values. Check `df['unix'].floordiv(10).mul(10).map(dict(zip(arr[:, 0] // 10 * 10, arr[:, 1])))`